# How backpropagation through gradient descent represents the error after each forward pass

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, gradient

I understand that the main difference between Stochastic Gradient Descent (`SGD`) vs Gradient Descent (`GD`) lies in the way of how many samples are chosen while training. That is, `SGD` iteratively chooses one sample to perform forward pass followed by backpropagation to adjust the weights, as oppose to `GD` where the backpropagation starts only after the entire samples have been calculated in the forward pass).

My question is: When the Gradient Descent (or even mini-batch Gradient Descent) is the chosen approach, how do we represent the error from a single forward pass? Assuming that my network has only a single output neuron, is the error represented by **averaging** all the individual errors from each sample or by **summing** all of them? To me this sounds like an implementation-dependent manner but I want to know if there is such a conventional way of that.

Comment: Please refrain from asking the same question on both Cross Validated and Data Science SE. There is no value in dispersing answers across the two sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of them, it a measure of the loss generated by the current weights of the model. If you use sums it gives you a big loss bigger your "batch", generally we use expectation to normalize the loss irrespective of the size of your "batch"